# Retain/release couple for CCObject necessary?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Can somebody explain why retain and release here? I can't see it is necessary.

Code as follows, thanks.

```
void CCDictionary::setObject(CCObject* pObject, const std::string& key) {
    CCAssert(key.length() > 0 && pObject != NULL, "Invalid Argument!");
    if (m_eDictType == kCCDictUnknown)
    {   
        m_eDictType = kCCDictStr;
    }   

    CCAssert(m_eDictType == kCCDictStr, "this dictionary doesn't use string as key.");

    CCDictElement *pElement = NULL;
    HASH_FIND_STR(m_pElements, key.c_str(), pElement);
    if (pElement == NULL)
    {   
        setObjectUnSafe(pObject, key);
    }   
    else if (pElement->m_pObject != pObject)
    {   
        CCObject* pTmpObj = pElement->m_pObject;
        pTmpObj->retain();
        removeObjectForElememt(pElement);
        setObjectUnSafe(pObject, key);
        pTmpObj->release();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see the details of what the function `removeObjectForElement(pElement)` does.

It is safer to retain the pTmpObj if the function removeObjectForElement would access the field of what the pointer pTmpObj points to.

If the object which pTmpObj points to is released by another procedure, you may get BAD_ACCESS error when call the `removeObjectForElement` method here.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x containers (`CCDictionary`, `CCArray`) `retain`s object when it's added, and `release` when object removed from container. Container itself is interface to another structure, ccArray or uthash, that does not use cocos2d-x's reference counting system and operates with raw data instead of `CCObject`s.

Most of CCObjects are `autorelease`d. Autoreleased object deleted at the end of update cycle, if it's reference counter hits 1 (retained only by list of autoreleased object). Autoreleased object can safely be removed from container, then added into another container inside single update cycle.

But if object is not autoreleased, it's deleted immediately when reference counter hits 0. So, when cocos2d-x container call `release`, object can be deleted, but object's pointer can still be stored in uthash or ccArray.

To protect object from being deleted, when data structure stores it's pointer, we `retain` object, then `release` it at the end of procedure.

This pattern also should be used, for example, when we move node from one parent to another:

```
node->retain();
node->removeFromParent();
newRoot->addChild(node);
node->release();
```

Usually, node is autoreleased, and it's safe to move it this way. But if node is not autoreleased, `removeFromParent` call can delete it, and `node` becomes garbage pointer.